# How to apply DISTINCT sql query on some of fields and return all columns?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

How i could achieve distinct for some of fields only and return result set include all columns ?

below is sql query:

```
       SELECT DISTINCT FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4,FIELD5
       FROM T1
       RESULT COUNT - 5000
       Observation - it is distinct for all five fields as DISTINCT APPLIED ON WHOLE RECORD.
                      BUt, FIELD1, FIELD2,FIELD43 are just duplicated and vary only FIELD 4, AND field5
```

Another sql query (Just skipped last two columns).

```
       SELECT DISTINCT FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3     --SKIPPED FIELD4,FIELD5
       FROM T1
       RESULT COUNT - 3000 
      OBVESERVATION - it shows only distinct record for all three field.
```

PROBLEM: i need distinct record for three fields only (FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3) and it should include - FIELD4,FIELD5

How it could achieve.

Thank You

Comment: So, there are different values in `FIELD4` and `FIELD5` for distinct values of fields 1-3 - SQL Server won't *guess* which of those values you want - you have to *tell* it how to select just one of those values. So, what's the rule?

Comment: Either you have to display all 5 fields, or only 3 fields.
If you want to distinct 3 fields, and also display field 4 and field 5. It is not possible, or you can aggregate function for field 4 & 5 as mentioned in dnoeth's answer.

Comment: Ya, But i want correct mapped vaue for field4 and field5. IF use aggreate, it will not give correct value.

Comment: suppose your table have data like (1,2,3,a,b) & (1,2,3,c,d)
What data should come in result?
because field 1,2 & 3 have same values.

Comment: hmmm. If result set record is returned for 'c,d' column then, it should be (1,2,3,c,d)'. Not the other (1,4,5,e,f).Actually, these fields are - some of ID fields and some of fields for Last updated date which has some minor date difference. though, right, 1,2,3 are same so ,it would be no mearning to preserver FIELD4,FIELD5 value but, would like to ensure, it applies on same records only and not to different like (1,2,3,c,d) and (1,2,5,e,f) and whiiever in result , it should be return with related FIELD4,FIELD5.

Comment: so, I think you can use dnoeth's first answer
which will give you first row in case field 1,2,3 are same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What do you want to be returned for FIELD4 and FIELD5, the data of any of the rows with the same FIELD1-3?

```
select *
from
 (
   SELECT FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,FIELD4,FIELD5,
      ROW_NUMBER()
      OVER (PARTITION BY FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3
            ORDER BY FIELD4) as rn
   FROM T1
 ) as dt
where rn = 1;
```

Or just any data from any row?

```
SELECT FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3,MIN(FIELD4),MIN(FIELD5)
FROM T1
GROUP BY FIELD1,FIELD2,FIELD3
```

But this might return MINs from two different rows, so no actually existing row.

Comment: I want same ID (Field4,Field5) which belong to that particular row. Will it provide correct maping ?

Comment: First approach will preserve the Field4,Field5 for result record set ?

Comment: Yes, if you have any rule you can change the ORDER BY to sort the row you want first.